# How to Change the Order of an Item in a List in Java and be Thread Safe?

Tags: java, list, thread-safety

I have a list of items and when I check an item, it goes at the end of the list. I want the application to be thread safe.

Is the code of "checkItem" thread safe in regards to the list "items"?

```
  public class ItemListImpl implements ItemList {

        List<Item> items = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<Item>());

        /**
         * Checks an item and brings it at the end of the list
         */
        public void checkItem(int index) {
            Item item = items.get(index);
            item.check();

            synchronized (items) {
                items.remove(item);
                items.add(items.size(), item);
            }

        }
    }
```

(forget the fact that I use the item's index. I'll use the object or an id)

Comment: It changes a private property of the item (isChecked = true)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to realize that `items` is a synchronized list, and that a synchronized list uses itself as its primitive mutex.  This means that all of the individual list operations  AND ALSO the `synchronized` block are synchronizing on `items`.

Therefore, the only point at where stuff could happen in an unsynchronized fashion is in the gap between the `get` call completing and the start of the `synchronized` block.  So is that a problem?

Well lets consider what could happen:

- If some other thread moves the position of the `Item`, it doesn't matter.  We'll find simply move it to the end anyway.
- If some other thread removes the `Item`, it doesn't matter.  Our call to `remove` will return `false`, but we'll still add the Item back.

Problems only arise if it is possible for a given `Item` to appear at more than one place in the `items` list.  If that occurs, then it is possible that the code will move the items element at the wrong position to the end of the list; e.g.

1. Thread A calls get(42) to fetch Item I.
2. Thread B inserts Item I at position 1.
3. Thread A completes the check, and removes and readds Item I ... but since I now appears at position 1 as well, it actually removes and adds that copy, not the copy at position 42.

In short, the code is thread-safe if we can assume that the a given Item object can appear at most one time in the list.  If we can't assume that, then there is a risk that we will move the object at the wrong position.

It should also be noted that the code won't work properly in the case where a given Item can appear more than once.  The problem is that `remove(item)` removes the first reference to the `item` instance it finds, not necessarily the one at position `index`.  There are two ways to look at this.  If this behaviour is unintended, it is a bug.  If it is intended, then the thread-safety concern is a probably non-issue.

---

Either way, the code is safe with respect to the memory model, assuming that the `check` method is thread-safe.

Answer (score 0):

Make the following change to make it threadsafe.

```
 public void checkItem(int index) {
            synchronized (items){    
                Item item = items.get(index);
                item.check();          
                items.remove(item);
                items.add(items.size(), item);
            }

    }
```

Comment: Why do we have to put the items.get and item.check in the synchronized block?